# How to extract odds ratio values and put it in new table in r?

Tags: r

I calculated odds ratios using these lines of code:

```
exp(cbind(OR = coef(table1), confint(table1)))
exp(cbind(OR = coef(table2), confint(table2)))
exp(cbind(OR = coef(table3), confint(table3)))
exp(cbind(OR = coef(table4), confint(table4)))
```

Now I want to take these odds ratio values and confident intervals and display them altogether in one table.

```
# create matrix with 4 columns and 4 rows
data= matrix(c(1:16), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

# specify the column names and row names of matrix
colnames(data) = c('col1','col2','col3','col4')
rownames(data) <- c('row1','row2','row3','row4')

# assign to table
final=as.table(data)

# display
final
```

This is what I have so far, but I want to know how can I insert the values from the first 4 lines of code into the data object (in the sixth line of code above)? Thanks in advance.

This is part of the output for when I did
dput(table1)

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your data, or sample data? It is hard to determine what you want without seeing the data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your data look like, but if you are running multiple ORs off the same dateset, for instance, like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(outcome = sample(0:1, size = 500, prob = c(0.9, 0.1), replace = TRUE),
                   predictor1 = sample(1:5, size = 500, prob = c(0.5, rep(0.1, 3), 0.2), replace = TRUE),
                   predictor2 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                   predictor3 = runif(500),
                   predictor4 = runif(500))
```

Then you could run the following code to calculate the ORs and assign them to the same table:

```
or_list <- lapply(df[, -grep("outcome", names(df))], function(xx) {
  mm <- glm(outcome ~ xx, data = df, family = "binomial")
  cbind(OR = coef(mm),
        confint(mm)) 
})
or_table <- do.call(rbind, or_list)
```

Output:

```
# (Intercept) -2.36040257 -2.9352593 -1.8343196
# xx           0.04643377 -0.1347648  0.2226279
# (Intercept) -2.45315795 -3.2591111 -1.7954126
# xxB         -0.24371895 -1.3897369  0.8510593
# xxC          0.48550782 -0.4251974  1.4532664
# xxD          0.16174616 -0.8416161  1.1819062
# xxE          0.46072779 -0.4686637  1.4396996
# (Intercept) -2.01042902 -2.5985643 -1.4732949
# xx          -0.48570922 -1.5293831  0.5388964
# (Intercept) -2.60812958 -3.2878108 -2.0015640
# xx           0.70034596 -0.3309282  1.7558563
```

Note, if you wanted to remove the intercepts, just do:

```
or_list <- lapply(df[, -grep("outcome", names(df))], function(xx) {
  mm <- glm(outcome ~ xx, data = df, family = "binomial")
  cbind(OR = coef(mm),
        confint(mm))[-1, ]
})
```

If your model data are from different analyses and look like this:

```
model1 <- glm(outcome ~ predictor1, data = df, family = "binomial")
model2 <- glm(outcome ~ predictor2, data = df, family = "binomial")
model3 <- glm(outcome ~ predictor3, data = df, family = "binomial")
model4 <- glm(outcome ~ predictor4, data = df, family = "binomial")
```

You could do:

```
or_list2 <- list(model1, model2, model3, model4)
or_table2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(or_list2, function(xx) {
  cbind(OR = coef(xx), confint(xx))
}))

## remove intercepts:
#or_table2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(or_list2, function(xx) {
#  cbind(OR = coef(xx), confint(xx))[-1,]
#}))
```

If these dont work, please provide some sample data and I can modify the answer.

Comment: Model data are from different analyses. I used the last box of code above and it says "Waiting for profiling to be done..." and it doesn't load. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like it may be a data-specific issue (the "waiting for profiling to be done" is from the `confint` function) - could you edit your question to share your table 1-4 data using `dput(table1)` etc and pasting the output at the bottom of the question?

Comment: When I do dput(table1) etc it doesn't show the data. The data has 8500 entries with 20 columns if that helps